# Can I have git send out an email with the post-receive-email scripts if my repo is on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, git, email

I have seen a bunch of examples for sending emails out when a repo receives a new push, but they seem to all be for a repo on a linux machine, is this possible to do with my repo on a windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, even if you are running windows you can use any type of scripting language, e.g. Python or Ruby which are easy to install on windows. Just create a hashbang at the top of your script:

```
#!C:\Python26\python
```

With python it's a piece of cake to send mails, talk to a database or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Windows machines don't tend to come with easy built-in mail-sending scripts. You could, however, install a program to send mail, and then use that program in a `post-receive` hook.